# Adding a string into time member and saving to database

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, string, time, save

I have a `duration` column in my database table in which I want to insert a timespan, like 02:00 or 19:20 (hours and minutes), the column type is time. The user sees a form with two dropdown lists, one for the minutes and one for the hours:

```
=f.select :durationhours, options_for_select((0..23).to_a)
=f.select :durationminutes, options_for_select((0..59).to_a)
```

The form is generated with form_for, and I don't have any durationminutes or durationhours in my database so I'm using validates_acceptance_of in my model.

```
attr_accessible :durationhours, :durationminutes #not sure this line is necessary
validates_acceptance_of :durationhours, :durationminutes
```

When the form is submitted I'm trying to put hours and minutes together and save them into the database, but this is failing, without showing any errors (only Rollback is mentioned in terminal). What I want to do is something like:

```
@record.duration = params[:record][:durationhours].to_s.rjust(2, "0") + ":" + params[:record][:durationminutes].to_s.rjust(2, "0")
# but I even tried this, and it doesn't work:
@record.duration = "13:30"
```

Without the line above where I manually set duration, `@record.save` works fine. This is the error I'm getting with `@record.errors.inspect`after save is executed:

```
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x10ba5be08 @messages=#<OrderedHash {:durationhours=>["must be accepted"],
:durationminutes=>["must be accepted"]}>, @base=#<Record id: nil, details: "",
happened: "2013-04-11 02:19:10", duration: "2000-01-01 12:12:00", activity_id: 17,
created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, price: nil>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`validates_acceptance_of` is not the validation you want to use here. That validator validates that a boolean value is set.

That said, rather than creating a string, consider storing your duration as an integer.

```
self.duration = self.durationminutes.to_i.minutes + self.durationseconds.to_i
```

That will give you a duration in seconds, which you can store in a single integer field in your DB.

```
durationminutes = 10
durationseconds = 24
duration = durationminutes.minutes + durationseconds
=> 624

624 / 1.minute => 10
624 - 10.minutes => 24
```

Comment: But without `validates_acceptance_of` I wasn't able to add an hours and minutes dropdown to my form (form_for expects table columns) so how would I go about doing that?

Comment: add `attr_accessor :durationhours, :durationminutes` (not to be confused with `attr_accessible`. This will create getters and setters on instances of that class for those attributes.

Comment: Make sure you keep the `attr_accessible` directives, too. You need both. `accessor` creates getters and setters, `accessible` tells Rails that it's okay to mass-assign them.

Comment: Yes I just figured that out, thanks for the quick reply though :) One last question: any idea why it would be adding three minus signs before the number? I even tried clearing duration first but it keeps adding `---` before the number in database. I'm just using `@record.duration = hh.to_i.hours + mm.to_i.minutes`

Comment: That sounds like your value is being serialized to YAML before it's stored in the DB. Did you change the column type to an integer?

Comment: I had accidentally changed it to string, changing it to integer fixed everything. Thanks a lot for your help Chris

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
irb> time = '20'.to_i.hours + '05'.to_i.minutes
=> 72300 seconds
irb> Time.at time
=> 1970-01-01 21:05:00 +0100
```

I'm not sure why it changes to the +1 time on my console but you can get the utc by doing:

```
irb> Time.at(time).utc
=> 1970-01-01 20:05:00 UTC
```